# deploying to nexus

Tags: maven, deployment, nexus

I am trying to deploy artifacts to nexus. When I tried with local machine it worked fine. But when I tried the same setup by having nexus in another machine. It is throwing error.

[image]

I have configured the  `<server> with <id>, <username> and <password>` in settings.xml and same `<id>` is referred in pom.xml.

The nexus machine accepts 80 & 8080 ports. Do I need to enable any other port? I reset the deployment user password and using the same password in settings.xml. Please help me how to resolve this. Thanks.

EDIT:
This is the first time I am trying to setup and deploy Nexus. I am able to download the dependencies from Nexus. Only problem is I am unable to deploy

settings.xml

```
<servers>
    <server>
      <id>releases</id>
      <username>deployment</username>
      <password>deployment</password>
    </server>
     <server>
      <id>snapshots</id>
      <username>deployment</username>
      <password>deployment</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
```

pom.xml

```
<distributionManagement>

                     <repository>
                       <id>releases</id>
                       <name>releases</name>
                       <url>http://ie22dtvm60013:8080/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
                     </repository>

                     <snapshotRepository>
                       <id>snapshots</id>
                       <name>Internal Snapshots</name>
                       <url>http://ie22dtvm60013:8080/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
                     </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

I checked the 'System Feeds' in Nexus, it shows 'deployment' user is authenticated. But still I am unable to deploy.
[image]

[image]

Comment: The message "The target server failed to respond" sound like a network issue...Can you access the other machine via Browser ? (Nexus)

Comment: Yes. I am able to access the Nexus machine. Any other port other than 80, 8080 has to be opened?

Comment: How does you settings.xml file look like and the pom (distributionManagement section in particular)?

Comment: Have you checked to login on the nexus via the given credentials in settings and you are allowed to deploy an artifact via Nexus?

Comment: Yes. I am able to login to Nexus using deployment user credentials. But I didn't see the option to deploy a artifact in both local nexus & remote nexus machine.

Comment: That sounds like your configuration on Nexus is not correct and obviously you can't deploy via maven as well.

Comment: is there a firewall on your local machine?

nexus only needs one port for the http connections. so one of 80 or 8080 is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be that ipv6 is activated. Maven uses ipv6 if offered by the router but often networks are not fully configured to work with that yet.

Try setting -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true for your maven invocation of the deploy command.